# Unable to use Sieve to sort out Spam Mails to a Spam folder

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot, sieve

I have configured a mailserver with dovecot + postfix on Debian. I can send and recieve emails. Also the server detects spam emails.

Unfortunately, Sieve does not sort out Spam Mails to a Spam folder. Thats why I am here.

Here are some configuration files that I edited:

http://pastebin.com/tdiUWFsS

(couldnt copy them in here, cause else I couldn't post my question which would be marked as spam from serverfault)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create sieve scripts for doing it.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_%28mail_filtering_language%29#Example) has some examples.
This scripting is kind of tricky, i used trial & error for defining it